# What is available out there to generate a database model out of json files?

Tags: json, database, entity-framework, data-modeling

I would like to model a database from json structures. What are the options for doing this in the .NET framework ? Does Entity Framework has offers any built in support for it ?

Would my data structures be known beforehand, I could go with defining the model classes and using newtonsoft's JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, populating an EF code-first generated DB with  T instances.

But **my problem is my storing data structures are not known beforehand**.

As an example, say I have the following json data:

```
{
    p1: "x",
    p2: "y",
    p3: 1000
}
```

and

```
{   
    t1: "this is a text",
    o: { 
          x: "I am an object"
       },
    p1: "x"
}
```

I would like to have a SQL server database generated from this json data, rendering 2 tables following the structures of each of the two objects above. 
At first I thought I would be please enough with simple flattened structures, but of course it would be nice to add relation database features such as relationships (like linking the objects via "p1" property).

Comment: Maybe relational isn't the right way to go with this. Have you thought of using a document (i.e. NoSQL database)? They tend to store stuff as JSON, which you already have.

Comment: your second object cannot possibly be json. json is data-only. it cannot contain "executable" code, expressions, etc... static VALUES only.

Comment: @CraigW. Thanks Craig. I never worked with NoSQL dbs, although have read something about time ago. You must be right, I will change directions.

Comment: @MarcB: Well, I "created" the example for illustration purposes, and wanted to add as much "complexity" I could come up with. I never thought about what you just stated. Good point. Fixed my example, thanks.

Comment: @MarcB: I will, however, add a getter property, which is represented in json and is a function.

Comment: nope. that's still not json. it's javascript, but it's not json. [json](http://json.org) does not support functions/methods at all. it supports objects, but only as key:value pairs, no executable code can ever be encoded as json.

Comment: @MarcB: you're right. Removing it. (I meant... "ok right, a function will get no string representation at all, but a getter will. But still the representation will only be key/value pairs, what I have above is a javascript object, not the "object notation").

Answer (score 1):

In searching for an answer I just came across [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

.NET project: http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/